# ConcurrentModificationException when reading from GAE Datastore using JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I am querying the GAE datastore to retrieve a list of entities (using a dev gae with sdk 1.8.3) :

```
public List<OT> getAll() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query q = pm.newQuery();
    q.setClass(OT.class);
    try {
        return (List<OT>) q.execute();
    }
    finally {
        q.closeAll();
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

This is always throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the `pm.close()` line :

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection.close(DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.closeAllConnections(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:181)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager$1.preClose(AbstractStoreManager.java:260)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1112)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.internalClose(JDOPersistenceManager.java:359)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.releasePersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:1106)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:343)
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>[3.0, 4.0)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the following version of the DN enhancer:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am not doing any modifications to any objects from the collection, or to the collection itself. As a matter of fact, the errors occures even when the collection is empty...
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**Additional debug details**
I have entered debug mode on the pm.close() statement and found out that while iterating on the listeners, one of them is removing himself from the list of listeners:

```
447468239@qtp-1694835335-71@11277, prio=5, in group 'main', status: 'RUNNING'
  at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1.managedConnectionPostClose(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:247)
  at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection.close(DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl.java:147)
  at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.closeAllConnections(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:181)
  at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager$1.preClose(AbstractStoreManager.java:260)
  at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1112)
  at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.internalClose(JDOPersistenceManager.java:359)
  at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.releasePersistenceManager(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:1106)
  at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:343)
  at net.mycrub.jacasse.persistence.dao.GenericDAO.getAll(GenericDAO.java:43)
```

Code at ConnectionManagerImpl.java:247

```
                    // Remove this listener
                    mconn.removeListener(this);
```

This is not a listener I have added myself. It was actually a DN listener added during the `Query.closeAll()` statement. Should I keep either of these 2 "close" statements, are they redundant?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell what's going on with the excerpt you've posted. Typically `ConcurrentModificationException`s occur any time an arraylist has more than one iterator iterating over it, regardless of whether they actually modify anything in it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is it is occuring before I could even try to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public List<OT> getAll()
{
  List<OT> liResult = null;

  PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  Query q = pm.newQuery();
  try
  {
    q.setClass(OT.class);
    liResult = (List<OT>)q.execute();
  }
  finally
  {
    try
    {
      q.closeAll();
    }
    finally
    {
      pm.close();
    }
  }

  return liResult;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I have now switched to Objectify which is taking care of the complex wiring stuff. I may test your code later when I can spare some time.

Answer (score 0):

The `DatastoreManagedConnection#close()` method is simply

```
public void close() {
    for (ManagedConnectionResourceListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.managedConnectionPreClose();
    }
    // nothing to actually close
    for (ManagedConnectionResourceListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.managedConnectionPostClose();
    }
}
```

The `ConcurrentModificationException` cannot come from here directly as nothing in this code modifies the `listeners` `List`. Is it possible you have other code running in parallel and adding or removing from `listeners`, calling `addListener` or `removeListener`?

Comment: Thanks, I have added a few details to my question after making some analysis in debug mode.